# Inserting a Facebook retargeting script inside of jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, if-statement

I am using a Facebook tracking pixel on my site. The code snippet provided by Facebook looks like this:

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '289122114623663');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=289122114623663&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

Usually, I put this snippet above the `</body>` tag and go on my merry way, but in this case, I need to NOT run this script if there is a certain div showing on the page.

I had written a jQuery if statement like this:

```
if (!$('.partner-bar').is(':visible')) {
    $("#facebook-pixel").html(""); 
};
```

I was planning to put the entire Facebook snippet within the .html() method, thinking that would output the HTML in a div called #facebook-pixel when those conditions are met. but jQuery seems to not like having the  instead of the .html() method.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like the issue actually was a whitespace issue. The code that I had copy pasted into the .html() method had line breaks in it that broke the code... when I removed all line breaks and extra whitespace, it worked as expected.

Here was my final code:

```
if (!$('.partner-bar').is(':visible')) {
      $("#facebook-pixel").html("<script>!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');fbq('init', '289122114623663');fbq('track', 'PageView');</script><noscript><img height='1' width='1' style='display:none'src='https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=289122114623663&ev=PageView&noscript=1'/></noscript>"); 
    };
```